# Убрать дубликаты из массивов

Tags: php

Есть массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 0
            [NAME] => Все типы ресторанов
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 126
            [NAME] => Бизнес ланчи
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 128
            [NAME] => Кафе
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 130
            [NAME] => Кейтеринг
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 132
            [NAME] => Кондитерская
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 133
            [NAME] => Пироговая
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 134
            [NAME] => Пиццерия
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 27
            [NAME] => Ресторан
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 78
            [NAME] => Ресторан
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 135
            [NAME] => Ресторан
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 26
            [NAME] => Суши
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 138
            [NAME] => Суши
        )

)
```

Убрать дубликаты с помощью array_unique не удалось. Как быть?

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста пример, как удалить повторяющиеся массивы по ключу?

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его, нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Укажите ссылку на этот вопрос, если это обеспечивает необходимый контекст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну правильно. `array_unique()` удаляет дубликаты значений. А в этом массиве значение элемента тоже массив из двух элементов. Вначале нужно сделать новы массив с ключами из `ID` и значениями из `NAME`, а потом воспользоваться `array_unique()`.

**UPD:** А еще, что-то мне подсказывает, что это результат выборки из базы. Если так, то уникальные значения можно выбрать SQL-запросом.

Comment: Пример запроса: SELECT DISTINCT(TYPE_ID) AS ID, TYPE AS NAME FROM table WHERE CITY_ID = '2' ORDER BY TYPE ASC

Comment: Такой запрос выберет все уникальные названия и самые первые идентификаторы соответствующие этим названиям:

    SELECT MIN(TYPE_ID) AS ID, TYPE AS NAME
    FROM it_catalog_index
    WHERE CITY_ID = '2'
    GROUP BY TYPE
    ORDER BY TYPE ASC

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] massUnique (String [] strings){
    // returns String array with unique values
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (String s: strings){
        set.add(s);
    }
    String result[];
    Iterator <String> iterator = set.iterator();
    String [] resMassiv = new String[set.size()];
    int index = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        resMassiv [index] = iterator.next();
        index++;
    }
    return resMassiv;
}
```

Метод удалит дубликаты из массива Стриг

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.